# Display Difference of Date (days) Between Last and Last-1 Issue Of Each KEY1

Tags: window-functions

#### Table Definition

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST (
    KEY1 VARCHAR NULL
    Dt DATE NULL,
    ISSUE INTEGER NULL,
    );
```

#### Example Data

```
    INSERT INTO TEST
    VALUES
    (100, '9/01/2010', 5),
    (100, '14/01/2010', 10),
    (100, '13/01/2010', 9),
    (101, '08/10/2010', 12),
    (101,'25/01/2010', 23),
    (101,'01/01/2010', 3),
    (101,'20/01/2010', 22);
```

#### Data in Table

> ```
> KEY1 | Dt         | ISSUE
> ---: | :--------- | ----:
>  100 | 2010-01-09 |     5
>  100 | 2010-01-14 |    10
>  100 | 2010-01-13 |     9
>  101 | 2010-10-08 |    12
>  101 | 2010-01-25 |    23
>  101 | 2010-01-01 |     3
>  101 | 2010-01-20 |    22
> ```

#### Desired Operation

- For the `KEY1` column containing the values `100` the last `ISSUE` has a value of `10` and the n-1 `ISSUE` would be `9`. We need the difference of the `Dt` column for these two values.
- For the `KEY1` column containing the values `101` the last `ISSUE` has a value of `23` and n-1 `ISSUE` is in this case `22`. We need the difference of the `Dt` column for these two values.

#### Expected Output

```
 KEY1 | DIFF
------+------
  100 |    1
  101 |    5
```

[db<>fiddle with example data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a177efb1a27ee5e3a7b5273ab4089f79)

Comment: Your data shows the last issue for KEY 101 is 12 on 8 October 2010, not 23 on 25 January 2010? Should 08/10/2010 be 08/01/2010? Even with that, it's hard to see why the DIFF for KEY 101 should be 5 (I think it should be 23 - 22 = 1). Also the INSERT table name doesn't match the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the DBA.SE community. I have formatted your question and cleaned up the code to match SQL Server. If this isn't correct please add the correpsonding tag and I will adapt the db<>fiddle. Please [edit] your question if you can add any relevant details. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the code you need:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

CREATE TABLE #TEST (
    KEY1 integer NOT NULL,
    Dt date NOT NULL,
    ISSUE integer NOT NULL,
);

INSERT #TEST
    (KEY1, Dt, ISSUE)
VALUES
    (100, CONVERT(date, '9/01/2010', 103), 5),
    (100, CONVERT(date, '14/01/2010', 103), 10),
    (100, CONVERT(date, '13/01/2010', 103), 9),
    (101, CONVERT(date, '08/01/2010', 103), 12),
    (101, CONVERT(date, '25/01/2010', 103), 23),
    (101, CONVERT(date, '01/01/2010', 103), 3),
    (101, CONVERT(date, '20/01/2010', 103), 22);

SELECT
    W.KEY1, DIFF = W.ISSUE - W.prev 
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY T.KEY1
            ORDER BY T.Dt DESC),
        prev = ISNULL(LAST_VALUE(T.ISSUE) OVER (
            PARTITION BY T.KEY1
            ORDER BY T.Dt DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING), 0)
    FROM #TEST AS T
) AS W
WHERE
    W.rn = 1;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3def7eefd749e61b90b2e0db21957a00)